# Confused with custom read write lock implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have seen some posts about the custom `read-write lock` implementation in `java` using `wait/notify`. It looks like:

```
 public class ReadWriteLock{

  private int readers;
  private int writers;
  private int writeRequests;

  public synchronized void lockRead() throws InterruptedException{
    while(writers > 0 || writeRequests > 0){
      wait();
    }
    readers++;
  }

  public synchronized void unlockRead(){
    readers--;
    notifyAll();
  }

  public synchronized void lockWrite() throws InterruptedException{
    writeRequests++;

    while(readers > 0 || writers > 0){
      wait();
    }
    writeRequests--;
    writers++;
  }

  public synchronized void unlockWrite() throws InterruptedException{
    writers--;
    notifyAll();
  }
}
```

I cannot comprehend how it could correctly work, unless I have not understood correctly how `wait/notify` really works.  Assuming the `read` requests and consequently `Threads` are more, my questions are:

- If `read Threads` acquire repeatedly the lock on the instance, how could a `write Thread` increase the variable `writeRequests`, since it can be increased only within a `synchronized` method. Hence a `Thread` should acquire first the lock to do it (if I am not mistaken). As long as a `read Thread` calls `wait` only if `writeRequests` or `writers` are greater than `0` , how can a `write Thread` have the chance to acquire the lock?
- Based on the above presumptions and statements, how could more than one `read Threads` access a method at the same time, since they should first call `lockRead()` which is synchronized as well?

Comment: your approach is right.I tested your code and it is working properly.Just i need to know that when you are using unlockRead and unlockWrite methods?

Comment: `wait()` releases the lock while it does its thing.  Then, the `lock*` operations must be paired with the respective `unlock*` operations e.g. `rwl.lockRead(); try { /* ... */ } finally { rwl.unlockRead(); }`.  Why does `unlockWrite` declare `InterruptedException`?

Answer (score 0):

Edit : After seeing you edit to the question, you're asking what happens when multiple threads call `wait()` inside the same synchronized blocks -  see this for a detailed explanation on what is called 'releasing the monitor' - http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynchP.html

To simplify things:

- Synchronized methods are like `synchronized(this)` blocks.
- calling `wait()` inside `synchronized` blocks release the lock and switches the thread to WAITING state. in this scenario other threads can acquire the lock on the same object and possibly notify the other  waiting threads on state change (your unlock methods demonstrate that) by using the same object waited on (`this` in our case, because you're  using synchronized methods)
- If you map the possible scenarios for calling each method according to that priniciple you can see that methods are either non-waiting ( `unlockRead()`/`unlockWrite()`) - meaning they can block on mutual exclusion upon entry, but don't run any blocking code(and end swiftly). 
  Or, they are waiting but non-blocking ( `lockRead()`/`lockWrite()`) - Just like the unlock methods with the addition their execution could potentially be stalled, however they don't block, but rather wait in such scenarios.
- So in any case you can consider your code as non-blocking and therefor it doesn't pose any real issue ( at least none that I can see ).
- That said, you should protect against unlocking non-existent locks, causes that'll cause an undesired behavior where counters would go below 0 ( which would in turn affect the lock methods)

Comment: My question is how the above code could work as expected, since the whole logic lies in synchronized methods which can be accessed only by one Thread at the same time. Moreover, the methods synchronized on the same resource undergo mutually exclusion.

Comment: @arjacsoh I saw your edit and updated my answer to refer to the link that describes cooperative locking

Comment: @arjacsoh I updated my answer to simplify things a bit